# Getting the right display for a matplotlib table

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data to a table using `matplotlib`. My problem is I can't get the table to display properly.

When I run this:

```
    ncols = len(tableColumns)
    nrows = len(tableRows)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(ncols*wcell+wpad, nrows*hcell+hpad))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.table(cellText=tableValues,rowLabels=tableRows,
                  colLabels=tableColumns,loc='center')
    plt.show()
```

I get this:

[image]

I can not find how to control it to have the following results:

- table is fully withing the figure
- no re-sizing allowed
- the long row names (currently mostly out of view) show up completely

Thanks.

Comment: You can't fit a lot of long strings in a narrow width. Put some linebreaks in the long column header we can see and see if that helps.